# <c:forEach> consider same values?

Tags: java, jsp, loops, foreach

Hi i was wondering the behaviour of using in a JSP  the cycle

```
       <c:forEach > </c:forEach
```

on a java Collection formed by : 1 , 1, 2, 3

Assuming there's a

```
       <table></table>
```

around the the foreach, and every value of the collection is inside of

```
<tr></tr>
```

does it show four row or three? Does it consider the same values every time (like "1") or not?

1
1
2
3
or
 
1
2
3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c:forEach is nothing but a for loop for JSP and it works the same as for loop will work in core Java, if you want to skip the duplicates in jsp file you can do two things one is use a datastructure which won't allow duplicates like SET etc or you can use a c:if along with c:forEach in the JSP file which will check for duplicates and you can eliminate them in your table.

Answer (score 1):

c:forEach just iterates through the collection one by one. forEach does not have any special handling for duplicates. If the collection can contain duplicates it will not skip them.

If you don't want duplicates you should consider using a data structure that does not allow for duplicates in the first place, e.g. Set.